# android, Comparator sort wrong

Tags: android, sorting, comparator

I have a Comparator to sort by 3 values:

1. ORDER_BY_Points
2. ORDER_BY_Gdif // goals difference
3. ORDER_BY_Goals

First I get a array from a json string. I send the array to StandingsSort.ORDER_BY_RULES

```
Arrays.sort(addressArray, StandingsSort.ORDER_BY_RULES);
```

Here is my code:

```
static final Comparator<Standings> ORDER_BY_Points = new Comparator<Standings>() {
    public int compare(Standings a1, Standings a2) {
        return a1.points.compareTo(a2.points);
    }
};
static final Comparator<Standings> ORDER_BY_Gdif = new Comparator<Standings>() {
    public int compare(Standings a1, Standings a2) {
        return a1.Gdif.compareTo(a2.Gdif);
    }
};
static final Comparator<Standings> ORDER_BY_Goals = new Comparator<Standings>() {
    public int compare(Standings a1, Standings a2) {
        return a1.goalsP.compareTo(a2.goalsP);
    }
};

static final Comparator<Standings> ORDER_BY_RULES = new Comparator<Standings>() {
    public int compare(Standings a1, Standings a2) {
        int i = ORDER_BY_Points.compare(a1,a2);
        if(i == 0){
            i = ORDER_BY_Gdif.compare(a1,a2);
            if(i == 0){
                i = ORDER_BY_Goals.compare(a1,a2);
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
};

class Standings {

    String teamName;
    String goalsP;
    String goalsM;
    String Gdif;
    String points;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + teamName + ","  + goalsP + ":" + goalsM + "," + Gdif + "," + points + "";
    }
    public Standings(String teamName, String goalsP,
                String goalsM, String Gdif, String points) {
        super();
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.goalsP = goalsP;
        this.goalsM = goalsM;
        this.Gdif = Gdif;
        this.points = points;
    }
}
```

But the result is not OK! Here is the result

```
Name, Goals, GDif, Points
Team,11:9,2,10
Team,5:3,2,10
Team,9:2,7,11
Team,0:6,-6,2
Team,3:9,-6,2
Team,6:9,-3,3
Team,8:13,-5,3
Team,8:9,-1,5
Team,8:11,-3,5
Team,8:7,1,5
```

Why does the Comparator sort wrong?

Comment: Which sort did you use to obtain your result?

Comment: @clever_trevor Arrays.sort(addressArray, StandingsSort.ORDER_BY_RULES);

Comment: Please edit your post. You first gave the results and then told which sort you did after that. Adding to the confusion is "After that i do". Because it looks as if you do that after gotten the results. So better first tell which sort you use and then give the results.

Comment: Please give the definition of Standings.

Comment: Please add some code in which you instantiate those items so we can just copy, paste and try.

Comment: What is wrong with the output? What do you expect it to be?

Comment: Please give complete example code that we can copy/paste to examine. I already asked you. Not interested in help?

Answer (score 2):

Since you store the points as `String`s, "10" comes before "2", "3", and "5". If you want to compare these in order by the numerical value, you need to convert them into `int`s first.

Similarly, Gdif and Goals are compared as `String`s which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Good catch. But bettere would be to change all `String goalsP;
    String goalsM;
    String Gdif;
    String points;` in Standings to integers.